# Mount nginx configuration files inside docker container

Tags: nginx, docker

I would like to mount `nginx.conf` and `default.conf` to an nginx running container.

```
docker run --detach --tty --interactive --publish=8081:80 
-v $(pwd)/app:/var/www/ 
-v $(pwd)/configurations/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf 
-v $(pwd)/configurations/default.conf:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default.conf  
--name="my_container" my:dev
```

I have got a 404 error and when I logged into the docker container I found that the app directory was mount but the `default.conf` was the default one.

This is default.conf file:

```
server {

    root /var/www;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {

                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;

                fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include fastcgi_params;

                fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
                fastcgi_buffers 256 16k;
                fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
                fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
                fastcgi_read_timeout 240;

    }

}
```

Comment: Please post the content of your `default.conf` as well as any error messages from the nginx log

Comment: @warmoverflow I added the default.conf file. There is no errors in the log file.

Comment: Maybe you should check permission /var/www ?